# How to apply dynamically created template for Vue.js instance?

Tags: javascript, templates, vue.js

I am able to use a static template with a Vue.js instance as shown below. 
The content of the `firstPlaceholder` is replaced with the content of the template `staticTemplate` and the `text` property is rendered correctly.
(Might require Chrome to work correctly.)

However, if I create a template dynamically, the rendering does not work. The `secondPlaceholder` is missing. Maybe this is a timing issue?

=>How can I adapt my code to render the `secondPlaceholder` using the `dynamicTemplate`?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
</head>

<body>
  
    <template id = "staticTemplate">
      <div>{{text}}</div>
    </template> 
  
    <div id ="firstPlaceholder"></div>
  
    <div id ="secondPlaceholder"></div>      
 
 <script>
    
     var dynamicTemplate = document.createElement('template');
      dynamicTemplate.id = 'dynamicTemplate';
      var div = document.createElement('div');
      div.innerText = '{{text}}';
      dynamicTemplate.appendChild(div);
      
      var staticTemplate = document.getElementById('staticTemplate');
      document.body.insertBefore(dynamicTemplate, staticTemplate);
    
      new Vue({
        el: '#firstPlaceholder',
        template: '#staticTemplate',
        data: {
          text: 'My first text'
        }
      }); 
      
      new Vue({
        el: '#secondPlaceholder',
        template: '#dynamicTemplate',
        data: {
          text: 'My second text'
        }
      });       
     
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Related question:

[How to target custom element (native web component) in vue.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49071186/how-to-target-custom-element-native-web-component-in-vue-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [Dom template](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement),

> The HTML Content Template () element is a mechanism for
> holding client-side content that is not to be rendered when a page is
> loaded but may subsequently be instantiated during runtime using
> JavaScript.

`<template>` contains one content attribute, normally we will read template content by this attribute. so you may add your html into the content.

If directly `appendChild` to `<template>`, you can print out the html, then will find nothing already been added.

Simply fix: just change `dynamicTemplate.appendChild(childDiv)` to `dynamicTemplate.content.appendChild(childDiv)`

because some browsers may not support `<template>`, you may have to use `<div>` instead then hide it.

**PS:** I found some documents said the attribute=content of `<template>` is readonly [HTMLTemplateElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTemplateElement), probably use `div` instead `template` will be better.

**Also** you could try [vue render()](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#ad), it will be better for your case.

```js
function isSupportTemplate() {
  return 'content' in document.createElement('template')
}

function createVueInstance(supported) {
  if(supported) {//check browser whether support template
    var dynamicTemplate = document.createElement('template');
    dynamicTemplate.id = 'dynamicTemplate';
    var childDiv = document.createElement('div');
    childDiv.innerText = 'support <template>: {{text}}-{{text}}';
    dynamicTemplate.content.appendChild(childDiv); //apend your html to template content
    document.body.appendChild(dynamicTemplate)

    var staticTemplate = document.getElementById('staticTemplate');
    document.body.insertBefore(dynamicTemplate, staticTemplate);
  }
  else {
    var dynamicTemplate = document.createElement('div');
    dynamicTemplate.id = 'dynamicTemplate';
    dynamicTemplate.style.display = 'none'
    var childDiv = document.createElement('div');
    childDiv.innerText = 'not support <template>: {{text}}-{{text}}';
    dynamicTemplate.appendChild(childDiv); //append your html to template content
    document.body.appendChild(dynamicTemplate)

    var staticTemplate = document.getElementById('staticTemplate');
    document.body.insertBefore(dynamicTemplate, staticTemplate);
  }

  new Vue({
    el: '#firstPlaceholder',
    template: '#staticTemplate',
    data: {
      text: 'My first text'
    }
  }); 

  new Vue({
    el: '#secondPlaceholder',
    template: '#dynamicTemplate',
    data: {
      text: 'My second text'
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
       <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="createVueInstance(isSupportTemplate())">Support Template</button>
  <button onclick="createVueInstance(!isSupportTemplate())">Not Support Template</button>
    <template id = "staticTemplate">
      <div>{{text}}</div>
    </template> 
  
    <div id ="firstPlaceholder"></div>
  
    <div id ="secondPlaceholder"></div>      
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not directly usable in your example as is, but maybe you could obtain the desired result using [Async Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#Async-Components).