# How to create bidirectional binding from vue.js instance to custom native web component?

Tags: vue.js, binding, web-component

Below is an example for a custom web component `my-input`. I would like to bind the value attribute of my custom input component to the email attribute of a vue instance. (The example might require Chrome to support custom web components.)

=>How do I have to adapt my web component example to get the binding working?

If I replace `my-input` with a plain `input` tag, the binding works. Therefore, my syntax for the vue.js part seems to be just fine.

https://jsfiddle.net/j5f9edjt/

```js
 new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '#app-template',
  data: {
  //email data is blank initially
    email: ''
  }
})
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.4"></script>

<script>
  class MyInput extends HTMLElement {

  static get observedAttributes() {
        return ['value'];
    }
    
    constructor(){
       super();
       this.wrappedInput=undefined;
    }

    connectedCallback(){
        var self=this;
        if(!self.wrappedInput){
            var wrappedInput = document.createElement('input');
            wrappedInput.type='text';
            wrappedInput.onchange = ()=>this.wrappedInputChanged();
            self.appendChild(wrappedInput);
            self.wrappedInput = wrappedInput;
        }
    }
    
    attributeChangedCallback(attr, oldValue, newValue) {
      if(attr==='value'){
          console.log('attribute changed ' + newValue);
          if(this.wrappedInput){
             this.wrappedInput.value= newValue; 
          }   
                                                 
      } 
    }
    
    wrappedInputChanged(){
      console.log('wrapepd input changed')
     var newValue = this.wrappedInput.value;
      this.value = newValue;
    }
    
     get value() {
        console.log('get value')
    return this.getAttribute('value');
  }

  set value(newValue) { 
     this.setAttribute('value',newValue);     
      console.log('set value ' + newValue);
  }

  }
  window.customElements.define('my-input', MyInput);

</script>

<div id="app"></div>

<template id="app-template">
  <div>
  <my-input v-model="email"></my-input>
    <h1>
       You entered {{email}}
    </h1>
  </div>
  
</template>
```

I tried to dispatch an extra input event but that did not help:

```
     var myInput = new CustomEvent("input", 
        {
          detail: {
            message: "Hello World!",
            type: 'text',
          },
          bubbles: true,
          cancelable: true
        }
      );
      this.dispatchEvent(myInput);
```

Where can I find the source code for the v-model directive to understand what it does?

Related question:

[How to target custom element (native web component) in vue.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49071186/how-to-target-custom-element-native-web-component-in-vue-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make `v-model` work you need to make a wrapper component for your webcomponent. The wrapper will conform to the [requirements for using `v-model` with a component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components).

Alternatively, you can decompose the `v-model` into its two parts: set the `value` prop and handle `input` events. Vue doesn't seem to recognize a webcomponent as a native element as far as `v-model` goes.

```js
class MyInput extends HTMLElement {

  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ['value'];
  }

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.wrappedInput = undefined;
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    var self = this;
    if (!self.wrappedInput) {
      var wrappedInput = document.createElement('input');
      wrappedInput.type = 'text';
      wrappedInput.onchange = () => this.wrappedInputChanged();
      self.appendChild(wrappedInput);
      self.wrappedInput = wrappedInput;
    }
  }

  attributeChangedCallback(attr, oldValue, newValue) {
    if (attr === 'value') {
      console.log('attribute changed ' + newValue);
      if (this.wrappedInput) {
        this.wrappedInput.value = newValue;
      }
    }
  }

  wrappedInputChanged() {
    var newValue = this.wrappedInput.value;
    this.value = newValue;
  }

  get value() {
    console.log('get value')
    return this.getAttribute('value');
  }

  set value(newValue) {
    this.setAttribute('value', newValue);
    console.log('set value ' + newValue);
  }

}

window.customElements.define('my-input', MyInput);

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '#app-template',
  data: {
    //email data is blank initially
    email: ''
  },
  methods: {
    handleInput(event) {
      this.email = event.target.value;
    }
  },
  components: {
    wrappedMyInput: {
      template: '#wmi-template',
      props: ['value'],
      methods: {
        emitInput(event) {
          this.$emit('input', event.target.value);
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.4"></script>

<div id="app"></div>

<template id="app-template">
  <div>
    <my-input :value="email" @input="handleInput"></my-input>
    <h1>
       You entered {{email}}
    </h1>
    <wrapped-my-input v-model="email"></wrapped-my-input>
    <h1>
       You entered {{email}}
    </h1>
  </div>
</template>

<template id="wmi-template">
  <my-input :value="value" @input="emitInput"></my-input>
</template>
```

Comment: A variant of this without extra method definition in the vue instance is <my-input :value="email" @input="email = $event.target.value"></my-input> Maybe its possible to create a custom directive as shorthand for that, e.g. v-mymodel="email". My preferred solution would still be to adapt the web component somehow to directly work with v-model. Maybe a special event dispatched for that purpose would do the trick but I did not get it working.

Answer (score 0):

The `v-model` directive seems to check the type of the tag and handle them individually:

https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/src/platforms/web/compiler/directives/model.js

I did not get the `v-model` to work for my custom component without extra wrappers. (I gave up on understanding how exactly my case is handled in model.js.)

As an alternative to "decomposing the binding" as suggested by Roy J.

```
<my-input :value="email" @input="email = $event.target.value"></my-input>
```

I created a custom directive `v-property`. It works both for `my-input` and `input` (as used in my original example; did not try all possible cases):

```
<my-input v-property="email"></my-input>
<input v-property="email"></my-input>
```

--

```
Vue.directive('property', { 
  bind: function (el, binding, vnode) {
    var viewModel = vnode.context;
    var propertyName = binding.expression;
    el.addEventListener('input', (event)=>{ 
      var oldValue = viewModel[propertyName];
      var newValue = event.target.value;
      if(newValue != oldValue){
        viewModel[propertyName] = newValue;        
      }     
    });    

    viewModel.$watch(propertyName, ()=>{
      var oldValue = el.value;
      var newValue = viewModel[propertyName];
      if(newValue != oldValue){
        el.value = newValue;        
      } 
    });

  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7dqppqo2/